# Esp32: is OTA compatible with FREERTOS

Tags: esp32, ota

Can I use OTA along with FreeRTOS tasks on ESP32. I ask this because in the following  [example](https://github.com/SensorsIot/ESP32-OTA/blob/master/0TA_Template_Sketch/0TA_Template_Sketch.ino) OTA seems to be enabled if FreeRTOS is disabled. Can for example upload firmware that runs on both cores over OTA?
Example taken from OTA [template project](https://github.com/SensorsIot/ESP32-OTA) by Andrea's Speiss

Comment: You can't *not* use FreeRTOS on the ESP32. The whole ESP-IDF is based around it.

Comment: yes, you can...

Answer (score 1):

You can't *not* use FreeRTOS. The whole ESP-IDF is based around it. The Arduino `setup()` and `loop()` run in their own FreeRTOS thread.

If you "turn off" FreeRTOS then nothing will work.

Whatever that "template" is from it's of no use to you.

Answer (score 1):

I was also believing that it is not possible but I handle it thanks to this post below;

https://github.com/SensorsIot/ESP32-OTA/issues/8

I applied what ever shared and it works like a charm together both FreeRTOS and OTA features.

As summary you need to create 2 custom header which includes your wifi credentials and OTA function. The remaining is same mostly.

credentials.h

```
#pragma once
const char* mySSID = "SSID of your AP";
const char* myPASSWORD = "Password of your AP";
```

OTA.h

```
#ifdef ESP32
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESPmDNS.h>
#else
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#endif

#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>

#if defined(ESP32_RTOS) && defined(ESP32)
void ota_handle( void * parameter ) {
  for (;;) {
    ArduinoOTA.handle();
    delay(3500);
  }
}
#endif

void setupOTA(const char* nameprefix, const char* ssid, const char* password) {
  // Configure the hostname
  uint16_t maxlen = strlen(nameprefix) + 7;
  char *fullhostname = new char[maxlen];
  uint8_t mac[6];
  WiFi.macAddress(mac);
  snprintf(fullhostname, maxlen, "%s-%02x%02x%02x", nameprefix, mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
  ArduinoOTA.setHostname(fullhostname);
  delete[] fullhostname;

  // Configure and start the WiFi station
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Connection Failed! Rebooting...");
    delay(5000);
    ESP.restart();
  }

  // Port defaults to 3232
  // ArduinoOTA.setPort(3232);

  // No authentication by default
  // ArduinoOTA.setPassword("admin");

  // Password can be set with it's md5 value as well
  // MD5(admin) = 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3
  // ArduinoOTA.setPasswordHash("21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3");

  ArduinoOTA.onStart([]() {
    String type;
    if (ArduinoOTA.getCommand() == U_FLASH)
      type = "sketch";
    else // U_SPIFFS
      type = "filesystem";

    // NOTE: if updating SPIFFS this would be the place to unmount SPIFFS using SPIFFS.end()
    Serial.println("Start updating " + type);
  });
  
  ArduinoOTA.onEnd([]() {
    Serial.println("\nEnd");
  });
  
  ArduinoOTA.onProgress([](unsigned int progress, unsigned int total) {
    Serial.printf("Progress: %u%%\r", (progress / (total / 100)));
  });
  
  ArduinoOTA.onError([](ota_error_t error) {
    Serial.printf("Error[%u]: ", error);
    if (error == OTA_AUTH_ERROR) Serial.println("\nAuth Failed");
    else if (error == OTA_BEGIN_ERROR) Serial.println("\nBegin Failed");
    else if (error == OTA_CONNECT_ERROR) Serial.println("\nConnect Failed");
    else if (error == OTA_RECEIVE_ERROR) Serial.println("\nReceive Failed");
    else if (error == OTA_END_ERROR) Serial.println("\nEnd Failed");
  });

  ArduinoOTA.begin();

  Serial.println("OTA Initialized");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

#if defined(ESP32_RTOS) && defined(ESP32)
  xTaskCreate(
    ota_handle,          /* Task function. */
    "OTA_HANDLE",        /* String with name of task. */
    10000,            /* Stack size in bytes. */
    NULL,             /* Parameter passed as input of the task */
    1,                /* Priority of the task. */
    NULL);            /* Task handle. */
#endif
}
```

OTA Template sketch.ino

```
#define ESP32_RTOS  // Uncomment this line if you want to use the code with freertos only on the ESP32
                    // Has to be done before including "OTA.h"

#include "OTA.h"
#include "credentials.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Booting");

  setupOTA("TemplateSketch", mySSID, myPASSWORD);

  // Your setup code
  /*  Example
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  */
}

void loop() {
#ifdef defined(ESP32_RTOS) && defined(ESP32)
#else
  ArduinoOTA.handle();
#endif

  // Your code here
  /* Example
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  */
}
```